# How can I convert a dict to a JSON object?

Tags: python, json

I have a dict, `ast` that is stored as:

`{u'databaseConnections': {u'shard1': {u'username': u'user'}}}`

I want to convert this into JSON so I can do something like:

`user = dbConf['databaseConnections']['shard1']['username']`

I've tried using `json.dumps(ast, ensure_ascii=False)`, but this just gives me the error:

`print dbConf['databaseConnections']['shard1']['username']
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can already do that with your dictionary.  If you make `dbConf = {u'databaseConnections': {u'shard1': {u'username': u'user'}}}`, and then type in your code to assign it to `user`, you'll get `'user'` as an output - no conversion necessary.

Comment: Why do you need json.dumps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting this thing to JSON is unnecessary and counterproductive; you can just do

```
user = ast['databaseConnections']['shard1']['username']
```

with your `ast` dict directly. dicts are key-value mappings; JSON is text. You're trying to access your data as a key-value mapping, not serialize it and send it over the internet.